is it possible to create a css file as a prefab, but to be used in other css files?
i may be missing the answer im looking for as ive googled this already, but i keep seeing it being used in html. Which is true, but i mainly keep my style scripting in its own file to keep the html cleaner and more readable.
I was only looking to call another css file, into a css file, as sort of a prefab for a premade box of some sort, but i may be making this more complicated.
Or would it be easier to do a html with the style typed into it to create said prefab, and then just reference that whole file into where i may need it?
really just looking to make my project smaller and have as little repeated code as possible, if that makes sense.
im just looking for efficiency in my work and googling this, i may have missed what i was looking for but nothing truly stood out as to answer my question

Cascading Style Sheets: Use one CSS with General Rules
Then after that another file with more specific CSS Rules for that page.
So there is no need to import CSS Files, even if it is possible

see now i was definitely overthinking this. because the block would basically be the same setup on every page, with different looks around it. as long as the html setup for that block is the same it would just take over

ive figured this out, had an issue with linking the page specific css in head and it not styling the page specific parts, but instead linking the style in the actual page specific body of the html

There are different techniques here that you can use depending on the situation and preferences. Note that the choice of tool is always case-specific and can be opinion-based.
1 Linking multiple Stylesheets
The first obvious option is to link multiple stylesheets:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet-1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet-1.css">

This way the last stylesheet will override the previous stylesheet if conflicting rules have been declared. However, this only remains true as long as the specificity weight remains the same.
As such I highly recommend you to read into the MDN WebDocs - Specificity.
2 Using @import
YOu can use @import within CSS such as:
@import URL("link-to-url.css");

This allows you to import other files and create modular* CSS where you load all modules you want to use. This is a technique that helps inc creating frameworks where you can "pack" a CSS with different modules that you need to use.
The downside is, that if a module fails, there will be no default fallback, and as such you are dependent on the correct working and loading of those "modules".
MDN WebDocs - @import
3 Using SASS/LESS and import modules
The same as in step 2 you can use the @import rule to load specific .scss files where you don't need to call the the URL but the file names you want to import. The main difference here is though, that the engine will compile a single full CSS file from all the importated SASS/LESS files.
SASS Documentation - @import
